# Linking libraries

Tags: c++, linker, shared

I have some project with file:
`src/Test.cpp`.
 Now I make subproject for it with another file `src/TestWrapper.cpp` which includes `src/Test.hpp` (related to Test.cpp).

Sure, to build successful shared library with wrapper I have to link **Test.cpp** too.

Everything works. I have project with Test.cpp linked and subproject (shared library) which linkes Test.cpp too.

The problem: that shared library would be linked to the main project. Will I have any errors due to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put Test.cpp in your shared library. You can link your shared library without `Test.cpp`, it will just have some undefined symbols, which is perfectly normal for a shared library.

What you did will probably work but is dangerous and will make your software unmaintainable.

Comment: Hm, that shared library is module for python (written with boost.python). I have to use it in future from main app. Will that problem about undefined symbols dissappeared?

Comment: Yes, symbols will be defined in your main application and the loader will resolve them when running the application.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will work. I leave the question still not solved. But I'll mark it as soon as I will be sure that this issue is resolved.